# Simple Growth rate question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Company X has 7% market share and is growing 8% per year. Company Y has 10% market share and is growing 2% per year.  About how many years will it take X to pass Y? Show your work.

Comment: so I'm still really confused as to this, any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your work on the problem.

Hint : $(\frac {108}{100})^n* \frac 7{100}= (\frac {102}{100})^n* \frac {10}{100}$ where n is the number of years.

Try this.

Comment: well using the above formula I got 4^1.6607 is that correct..?

Comment: Apologies for the wrong expression.